# How do I find the "unwinding" rate of a polar equation of two variables?

Tags: derivatives, polar-coordinates

I was playing around with an online calculator and polar functions, seeing what kind of function transformations I could do with a slider. I had the equation:
$$
r =\cos(\sin(\tan(\frac{\theta}{c})))
$$
where c was constant. Then, I clicked the "play" button on c, making c increase by 0.05 every frame, and found some sort of unwinding behavior, as seen [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dcewfykazm). I also found that the farther $c$ was from 0, the slower it unwound. I feel like doing a derivative but I don't know *how* that applies to my problem. 

**My Question:**

How do I find the "unwinding rate" of a polar function of two variables? 

 
Thank you in advance, 
 Jonah

Comment: First try understanding the behaviour of $y=\cos\sin\tan(x/c)$. The behaviour of $r=\cdots(\theta/c)$ is the same thing, just wrapped around a circle.

Comment: Are you saying that the rate I am looking for is simply y'?

Comment: I'm saying look at what happens to the graph of $y = \cdots(x/c)$ when you click the "play" button on $c$.

Comment: The behavior is far more complex than you are seeing in your animation. For example, try changing your limits to only $0.1$ to $0.2$ with a step size of $0.001$. You will discover that it is winding and unwinding greatly. In fact, any time $c$ is irrational, you will find it "infinitely wound", but with rationals, The amount of winding (as counted by the number of densely covered regions) depends on the size of the reduced denominator.